# How to optimize this query for my school project

Tags: sql, oracle, mongodb, query-optimization

It's my assignment kindly help me to optimize below two queries.

Optimize assignment 1:

```
SELECT 
    n.node_id,
    MIN(LEAST(n.date,ec.date)) date
FROM 
    n, ec
WHERE 
    (n.node_id = ec.node_id_from OR n.node_id = ec.node_id_to)
    AND n.date - ec.date > 0
GROUP BY 
    n.node_id;
```

Optimize assignment 2:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles', tableA."date"), 'YYYY-MM') AS "date_month",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (tableB."date" IS NOT NULL) THEN tableB._id ELSE NULL END) AS "tableB.countB",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (tableC."date" IS NOT NULL) THEN tableC._id ELSE NULL END) AS "tableC.countC"
FROM 
    tableA AS tableA
LEFT JOIN 
    tableB AS tableB ON (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles',tableB."date"))) = (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles',tableA."date")))
LEFT JOIN 
    tableC AS tableC ON (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles',tableC."date"))) = (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles',tableA."date")))
WHERE 
    tableA."date" >= CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('America/Los_Angeles', 'UTC', DATEADD (month, -17, DATE_TRUNC('month', DATE_TRUNC('day', CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles',GETDATE ()))))
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    1 DESC 
LIMIT 500;
```

Comment: Is this the original form of the code?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? and what do we get for completing your homework ?

Comment: [oracle] or [mongodb]??? Two very different data stores. Please make your mind up

Comment: @Ihazkode yes original

Comment: @SudiptaMondal I tried nothing because according to my understanding it's accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use short alias that makes sql query shorter and cleaner.
Here is the optimized version of second query

```
SELECT DatePart(month, a.Date-8/24) date_month, 
  sum(case when b.date is Not null then 1 else 0 end) countb,
  sum(case when c.date is Not null then 1 else 0 end) countc,
FROM tableA a    
  LEFT JOIN tableB b 
     ON b.Date = a.Date -- Timezone offsets are not necessary, 
  LEFT JOIN tableC c  
     ON c.date = a.date -- both in same timezone 
WHERE a.date >= DateAdd(hour, 8,
            DATEADD (month,-17,DATE_TRUNC('month', 
             GETDATE () ))
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution for assignment #1

```
SELECT n.node_id, MIN(ec.date) as date
FROM n 
JOIN ec
  ON n.node_id IN (ec.node_id_from, ec.node_id_to) AND ec.date < n.date
GROUP BY n.node_id;
```

just using min(ec.date) instead of MIN(LEAST(n.date,ec.date)).
Because the JOIN already forces the ec.date to be lower than n.date anyway.

Also note that a where clause like

```
where (x >= y and x <= z)
```

can be changed to

```
where (x between y and z)
```